# Adding variable speed control to 3-speed bldc pool pump motor

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor, speed

I have several 1.5 hp 240 V bldc pool pump motors I've repaired and salvaged from work with plans to re-purpose them on certain projects, an upgraded high torque motor for my mini lathe being a good example.

One brand (Astral/Fabtronics) has a handy adjustable speed range between 500 to 2850 rpm in 50 rpm steps and adjustable start speed, however, it's relatively massive in size and would need adjustable pulleys to get a usable speed range for all materials.

The other brand (Fasco) is nice and compact when removed from its casing, however, it only has 3 speeds and runs a prime cycle for 5 mins where it's at max speed and can't be adjusted, making it about as useful as any old AC induction motor... Lame.

This is where I'm hoping to get a little advice. I've been researching like crazy trying to understand how I could add variable speed control to one of these high-powered motors, but all I'm coming up with is lower-powered hobby stuff with a steep learning curve programming chips and building circuits from scratch.

I already have too many projects so I don't really want to go down that rabbit hole; since these motors already have bldc power drivers and controllers I thought it would be easier to work out a method of controlling speed. I'm not finding any information from someone who has done similar and would appreciate any advice or if this is a project worth investing any time in.

Comment: You can't hack the speed of a BLDC motor driver unless you have the software or write your own and if you do it's trivial. In any case, the built in driver is probably no good for your application since a pump is very different than a lathe. Maybe just remove the motor driver and replace it with a 2HP VFD. A BLDC is essentially a synchronous AC motor anyways. Might run you $100-200USD for the cheapest kind. I'd go a bit better than that since for a lathe there are cases where you want very low speeds under torque so you want field oriented control, or maybe even sensored control.

Comment: Appreciate the response and confirming there is no simple hack. If I remember correctly the motor controller on the fasco is a microchip pic16f(690?) I got excited when I discovered the vedder custom esc that uses a similar chip, but seems the software is built around a 60v limit and any kind of chip programming is basically alien to me right now.

Comment: I hadn't considered the use of a vfd with a bldc motor, I really like that idea and will investigate further. My backup option was to try and use a vfd with a single phase induction motor, but the bldc as a 3 phase motor makes a lot of sense. Thanks